# How to change boot logo in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, bootsplash

I want to change my Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon boot image manually.

So, I replaced the image located at:

```
/lib/plymouth/themes/mint-logo/logo.png
```

with mine.

The logo changes at shutdown but not at boot.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/736423/changing-kernel-bootsplash-image

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just type: `sudo update-initramfs -u`.

Answer (score 7):

Here are the steps you will need to follow : 
Goto following location

```
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/mint-logo
```

Change the mint-logo.png to the choice of your image.
You will need the root permission to change it so open it as root.
Then checkout this file : mint-logo.script
This file contains the code which shows how the logo and background should look, so change accordingly.

Then type following command :

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now reboot to look at the changes in your bootsplash screen.

Answer (score 1):

For me after doing `sudo update-initramfs -u` the logo had changed for shutdown but not for boot.
The logo at boot changed only after turning on virtualization.
If you nothing is working for you, you can give it a try by going to your BIOS and enabling virtualization.

Note: I am not sure how this relates, but it worked for me, so i thought it is worth posting, although, i do realize virtualization should not have any effect on boot logo.

(Using Linux Mint 18.2)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth, you need to edit GRUB and also update your initramfs...