# How to change boot logo in linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, bootsplash

Ok, so i've got identical problem as in this topic: [How to change boot logo in linux mint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153975/how-to-change-boot-logo-in-linux-mint/440786)
But nothing I've tried worked. Also I can't change logo to default one. It's just black screen when booting.
Can anyone help?

> I want to change my Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon boot image manually.
>
> So, I replaced the image located at:
>
> /lib/plymouth/themes/mint-logo/logo.png with mine.
>
> The logo changes at shutdown but not at
>
> boot.

Comment: You're just saying you've still got the same problem after trying their solutions. Without any more input, how do you expect to get another more accurate answer? Just scour the internet and if you find the answer add it to that question.

Comment: What does `plymouth --show-splash` show?

Answer (score 2):

After changing the picture you need to update the grub.cfg file.To do this open the terminal and type this command

```
# update-grub
```