# Show bootsplash image without rebooting

Tags: boot, images, slackware

I have slackware 14.2 installed on a spare computer without any GUI. My child loves to see the penguin bootsplash when the computer restarts and the kernel loads. Is there anyway to show them without having to reboot?

Comment: research `slackware custom bootsplash` .... it may point you to the location of the bootsplash image and to any available bootsplash testing scripts that you could run to view the image

Comment: found this ..... i don't know if slackware may be similar ....... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153975/how-to-change-boot-logo-in-linux-mint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean their logo, then this  can be found from their site.
http://www.slackware.com/~msimons/slackware/grfx/shared/slackpenguinlogo.jpg

From a non-X screen you can tools such as `fbi` ( https://slackware.pkgs.org/14.2/slackonly-x86_64/fbida-2.14-x86_64-1_slonly.txz.html ) to draw the image on a console.

e.g.

```
fbi -a slackpenguinlogo.jpg
```